# Which Open Source license prohibits sale of work and derivative works?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I'm looking to start a open source project with a friend and we were discussing open source licenses but neither of us really understand the vague and unclear terms and conditions of the licenses.

We are fine with:

- Distribution
- Creation of derivative works

But do not want:

- Sale of our work
- Sale of derivative works
- Use of our work without attribution in any form

Can you guys recommend any Open Source licenses that fulfill those criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible to put this restriction on your code and still count as "open source", at least under the widely accepted [open source definition](http://www.opensource.org/docs/osd).

The relevant paragraph:

> 1. Free Redistribution
>
> The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away the software as a component of an aggregate
>   software distribution containing programs from several different
>   sources. The license shall not require a royalty or other fee for such
>   sale.

i.e. if you want to count as open source, you have to allow others to sell your software either in its current form or as a derived / aggregate work.

If you want to be open source but still want a commercialisation option, one option is to release your software under a **dual license**, with one license being copyleft (like the GPLv3) and the other being a proprietary license. Others can then use your software under the terms of the GPL, but if they want to incorporate your software into a closed source software product they will need to buy your proprietary license.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this one:

> We are fine with:
>
> •Distribution
>   •Creation of derivative works
>
> But do not want:
>
> •Sale of our work
>   •Sale of derivative works
>   •Use of our work without attribution in any form

Comment: Because we have no legal experience whatsoever, we are looking for a license that has a substantial reputation and would hold up in court.

Comment: If you have no money to go to court, no license will be useful. This one doesn't prevent from abuse but informs honest developers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CC-BY-NC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/), that is the *Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike* license. (full Creative Commons Legal Code [here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/legalcode)) The [Choose a license](http://creativecommons.org/choose/) page too recommends the same with your requirements: No commercial uses, but with (attributed) modifications allowed.

Section 4.c. of this license specifically states:

> You may not exercise any of the rights granted to You in Section 3 above in any manner that is primarily intended for or directed toward ***commercial advantage or private monetary compensation.***

(Section 3 deals with copying/adapting/distributing etc.)

No matter which license you choose, I strongly recommend going through the [Creative Commons FAQ](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions).

Comment: Thanks, but Creative Commons does not recommend applying their licenses to software since they do not explicitly account for it.